# How can I add a textbox input to title bar in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would like to add some filter to a custom treeview.

Is there a way to add the filter text input to the title bar like in this example (there is one similar in the "problems" view as well)?

[image]

Comment: The TreeView API for extensions is not the full possibilities of the VSC. You need to move over to use a WebviewView, an HTML page with JavaScript